# MySQL unwanted automatic replacing \n to linebreaks when storing data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using PHP to pass a query like this:

```
"UPDATE `prove750_mrdias`.`stringsMrDias` 
SET `conteudo` = '$conteudo' 
WHERE `stringsMrDias`.`ID` = $id;"
```

when I `echo $conteudo` I get `Sobre\nmim` as expected.

But after the query, I look at the database and the value stored is the formatted string:

'sobre

mim'

That's causing all sorts of problems when parsing the data back to my application.

If I go to phpMyAdmin and pass the value of `$conteudo` manually it maintains the expected behavior, only when querying the replace is happening without calling it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Escape the `\n` character, but I don't see how it would cause "problems". Its just 1 application decides to format the text and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Escaping issue. Use prepared statements.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's an issue of interpolation.  You can kill two birds with one stone by using *prepared statements*.  By using *prepared statements*

1. your data won't be corrupted or need to be manually handled by you,
2. your application will not be subject to security issues a la [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

This might look like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `prove750_mrdias`.`stringsMrDias` SET `conteudo` = ? WHERE `stringsMrDias`.`ID` = ?";
$preparedStatement = $pdo_handle->prepare( $sql );
$preparedStatement->execute([$conteudo, $id]);
```

That is, you first tell the database the *form* of the query you want executed, and then -- in a separate call -- you send the arguments to that query.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at the prepared statements documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php
Example,

```
$conteudo = nl2br($conteudo);
```

Then store into database.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements was the right direction.

After looking at the mysqli documentation I ended up with a code like this:

```
`$sql = "UPDATE `prove750_mrdias`.`stringsMrDias` SET `conteudo` = (?) WHERE `stringsMrDias`.`ID` = (?)";

if (!($stmt = $con->prepare($sql))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('ss', $conteudo,$id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}


if (!$stmt->execute()) {
     echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}`
```

Had to use the `bind_param()` as `execute()` don't accept any parameters.